# WPF - Why does UI Lock Up?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, locking, dispatcher, unresponsive-progressbar

If we use the task based async pattern with async and await keywords, there is no issue with the UI locking up. For example, we can spend 10 seconds loading data from the server and happily display a wait indicator at the same time. However, when running complex tasks on the UI thread, the thread locks up and the animation in the wait indicator just freezes.

Of course, one strategy could be to avoid hefty UI altogether, but this is not really an option in this case. I am loading hundreds of TreeViewItems on to the screen. This is clearly causing the UI to lock up.

I have tried putting the work on the control's Dispatcher like this, but it doesn't help:

```
   var action = new Action(() =>
    {

       SchemaTree.Items.Clear();

       foreach (var assemblyStructure in assemblyStructures)
       {
           var assemblyNode = CreateTreeNode(SchemaTree.Items, assemblyStructure.Assembly.Name.Replace("Adapt.Model.", string.Empty), assemblyStructure.Assembly, "/Icons/Schema.PNG");

           foreach (var theNameSpace in assemblyStructure.Namespaces)
           {
               var namespaceNode = CreateTreeNode(assemblyNode.Items, theNameSpace.TheNamespace.Name, theNameSpace.TheNamespace, "/Icons/Namespace.PNG");

               foreach (var classInfo in theNameSpace.Classes)
               {
                   CreateClassInfoNode(theNameSpace, classInfo, namespaceNode);
               }
           }
       }
   });

    await SchemaTree.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.Background, null);
```

If I move the work on to a Task with Task.Run it actually stops the UI from locking up, but obviously, I get a cross threading violation.

```
  var action = new Action(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                SchemaTree.Items.Clear();

                foreach (var assemblyStructure in assemblyStructures)
                {
                    var assemblyNode = CreateTreeNode(SchemaTree.Items, assemblyStructure.Assembly.Name.Replace("Adapt.Model.", string.Empty), assemblyStructure.Assembly, "/Icons/Schema.PNG");

                    foreach (var theNameSpace in assemblyStructure.Namespaces)
                    {
                        var namespaceNode = CreateTreeNode(assemblyNode.Items, theNameSpace.TheNamespace.Name, theNameSpace.TheNamespace, "/Icons/Namespace.PNG");

                        foreach (var classInfo in theNameSpace.Classes)
                        {
                            CreateClassInfoNode(theNameSpace, classInfo, namespaceNode);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        });


        await SchemaTree.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.Background, null);
```

**Any ideas on how to tell the UI to lessen the priority of this work so that the wait indicator has a chance to animate, and the whole UI doesn't lock up?**

Comment: You can try breaking the action into small actions, each action just do one assembly structure. Then await one action at each time; You got many Dispatcher.BeginInvoke calls instead of one enormous action, but the UI can get a chance to run the animator.

Comment: Yes - you are right. I have done that in another place in my code, and I can see a difference. The problem is that this causes another problem. In the case of the TreeView, I can literally see the tree nodes populating one by one in front of my eyes, and I cannot tell when all nodes have been rendered.

Comment: Also, this cannot be done with a ListBox for example because I am handing over the creation of ListBoxItems to the control itself to do.

Comment: If you start the task and then use the dispatcher to actually produce the end result (i.e. add treeViewItem) you should be good to go. Also I would recommend using xaml in this case with a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and a collection in a viewModel. [MSDN link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikehillberg/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step/)

Comment: "*I am loading hundreds of TreeViewItems on to the screen*" - you should avoid this altogether. Use virtualization and create the UI only for those elements that are currently visible. For the invisible, only load their data asynchronously w/o cross thread access problems. Use DataTemplates.

Comment: This is sound advice. But, not always possible. We are porting from Silverlight to WPF currently. The thing about this is that the UI never locked up in Silverlight. The exact same code that runs instantaneously in Silverlight (loading hundreds of nodes) locks up the UI in WPF. There's no point in dropping out to lazy loading when there is no performance problem. The problem only came in with WPF. My guess is that Microsoft simply made heaps of performance enhancements in Silverlight.

Comment: The answer to my original question is that the Dispatcher (that handles message pumping) executes everything in a first in first out sequence and is not multi threaded. That means that if you flood the Dispatcher with messages, the UI will lock up. Thankfully, the problem is easy to solve. All I need to do is call Dispatcher.Yield() in the loop and the problem magically goes away. What it does is allow other UI work to execute in between the creation of the nodes. @kennyzx this is better than Dispatcher.BeginInvoke because that requires a change in control flow.

Comment: Please post it as an answer. It sounds like the Application.DoEvents in WinForms and I assume it is provided for the same purpose? Will check the docs and do some experiments, I have not used it before.

Comment: I will, but I want to take some time to document this properly as it's a commonly misunderstood topic. People's first response is: use task based async (which doesn't solve anything). The next go to is: don't put a lot of work on the UI thread (which is fair enough but not necessary in most cases). Yes, it is like Application.DoEvents which dates right back to VB6, but Application.DoEvents apparently causes reentrancy problems.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my original question is that the Dispatcher (that handles message pumping) executes everything in a first in first out sequence and is not multi threaded. That means that if you flood the Dispatcher with messages, the UI will lock up. Thankfully, the problem is easy to solve. All I need to do is call

```
await Dispatcher.Yield();
```

in the loop and the problem magically goes away. What it does is allow other UI work to execute in between the creation of the nodes.

This answer is a placeholder until more detail is added here.